# How to do views bulk operations on all matches, not just a page

Tags: views, 9

I have a lot of nodes to delete on a Drupal 9 site. I thought I could use the Content view, select the node type, click select all and Delete.

However it seems that select all only selects the visible nodes, i.e. page 1. I have many pages of results!

Is there a way to select *all* matched rows?

Comment: That functionality is built in (or at least used to be), does this help? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/2904116

Comment: Like @Clive notes, this feature is already there.  You should get the option to select all rows; if that doesn't work, try changing your admin theme (or site theme if you are using VBO on a regular page) to one of the core themes.

Comment: ah, wait a mo. I was confused because I thought VBO was in core. Now I see that what I saw as "Node operations bulk form" is something else, and that views_bulk_operations does still exist as a separate module that adds the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm going to write this up as an answer in case it's useful to anyone else doing d7 to d9 upgrades, unless anyone else wants to.

Answer (score 2):

Do not be confused between "node operations bulk form" and "views bulk operation form".

In Drupal 9 (probably 8, can't recall), Views got incorporated into core. Knowing this, and seeing "node operations bulk form" on the *view* which now in D9 is used for the `/admin/content` page I thought the Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module must also be included. But it's not.

So you still need to install [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/) if you need this functionality.

Then you need to add the Views Bulk Operations field to the Content view, and remove the Drupal core one named "node operations bulk form" (otherwise it [crashes](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/3229438#comment-14386462)).